# Why does pitest work with maven on the commandline, but not in Jenkins-Pipeline?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jenkins-pipeline, pitest

I have a strange problem here for which I could not find the reason:

When using pitest with maven (and java 11) on the commandline it works as expected, but when running it on the Jenkins-Server via declarative pipeline it results in an error.

Part from my maven pom:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
      <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.8</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
          <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Part from my Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('MutationTesting')
 {
  steps
   {
    bat 'mvn --batch-mode org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage'
   }
 }
```

Before that the following maven commands will be called from the pipeline:

> mvn --batch-mode clean
>
> mvn --batch-mode compile
>
> mvn --batch-mode compiler:testCompile surefire:test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

When calling exactly these commands on the commandline then pitest works perfectly.

When comparing the logging results, then they are nearly equal.

Log output from commandline:

> PIT >> FINE : Maximum available memory is 3609 mb
>
> PIT >> FINE : MINION : Installing PIT agent
>
> PIT >> INFO : Sending 13 test classes to minion
>
> PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:51:20 PIT >> FINE : Expecting 13 tests classes from parent
>
> PIT >> FINE : Tests classes received
>
> PIT >> INFO : Checking environment
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:51:20 PIT >> INFO : Found  1 tests
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:51:20 PIT >> INFO : Dependency analysis reduced number of potential tests by 0
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:51:20 PIT >> INFO : 1 tests received
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:51:20 PIT >> FINE : Running 1 units
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:51:20 PIT >> FINE : Gathering coverage for test Description [testClass=de.test.Tests, name=creation()]
>
> PIT >> FINE : Coverage generator Minion exited ok
>
> PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 0 seconds.
>
> PIT >> FINE : Used memory after coverage calculation 42 mb
>
> PIT >> FINE : Free Memory after coverage calculation 201 mb
>
> [... Mutations output cut]

Log output from Jenkins-Pipeline:

> PIT >> FINE : Maximum available memory is 1813 mb
>
> PIT >> FINE : MINION : Installing PIT agent
>
> PIT >> INFO : Sending 13 test classes to minion
>
> PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:46:28 PIT >> FINE : Expecting 13 tests classes from parent
>
> PIT >> FINE : Tests classes received
>
> PIT >> INFO : Checking environment
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:46:29 PIT >> INFO : Found  1 tests
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:46:29 PIT >> INFO : Dependency analysis reduced number of potential tests by 0
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:46:29 PIT >> INFO : 1 tests received
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:46:29 PIT >> FINE : Running 1 units
>
> PIT >> INFO : MINION : 08:46:29 PIT >> FINE : Gathering coverage for test Description [testClass=de.test.Tests, name=creation()]
>
> PIT >> FINE : Coverage generator Minion exited ok
>   PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 1 seconds.
>   PIT >> FINE : Used memory after coverage calculation 43 mb
>   PIT >> FINE : Free Memory after coverage calculation 177 mb
>   PIT >> INFO : Created  0 mutation test units
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time:  3.644 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-06T08:46:29+02:00
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.4.8:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project multiuploader: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.4.8:mutationCoverage failed: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.
>   [ERROR] See http://pitest.org for more details.

So I could only assume that there is a difference in the environment - but which one? Or is it is a bug in pitest?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that pitest is being executed by jenkins in an environment where the tests have not been compiled.

The most robust approach is to bind pitest to the test phase in a profile rather than invoke the goal directly.

```
<profile>
  <id>pitest</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
          <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.8</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>pitest</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>mutationCoverage</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>  
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

Pitest can then be run with

```
mvn -Ppitest test
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail why pitest is executed in an environment where the tests have not been compiled? As I described my pipeline has compiled the tests already.

Comment: I can't as (if this is what is happening) it is an issue with the environment/jenkins.

Comment: I am sure that the tests have been compiled in the jenkins environment - for more please have a look at my Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183989/maven-lifecycle-within-jenkins-pipeline-how-to-best-separate-responsibilities
This proves it, because I run tools like SpotBugs/FindBugs that also require the compiled code.